# Elixir receiving data from a system command

Tags: elixir

I have this command that I wish to execute in elixir (`System.cmd("tail", ["-n", "1", "-f", "/var/log/syslog"])`) which is supposed to send a new line each time a log is being added to the `syslog` file however, running simply like that, the code just stales.

I know I'm supposed to detach it somehow and start receiving from it but I don't have a single clue how to do that...elixir is still really new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using `System.cmd`, but you can use `Port.open/2` for this. Here's how to spawn a process in the background and then use `receive` to receive its input, whenever available:

```
defmodule Main do
  def main do
    port = Port.open({:spawn, "tail -n 1 -f a.txt"}, [:binary])
    loop(port)
  end

  def loop(port) do
    receive do
      {^port, {:data, data}} ->
        IO.inspect data
        loop(port)
    end
  end
end

Main.main
```

In a separate shell, I ran this:

```
$ echo 1 >> a.txt
$ echo 2 >> a.txt
$ echo 3 >> a.txt
$ seq 4 10 >> a.txt
```

and the program printed this:

```
"1\n"
"2\n"
"3\n"
"4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n"
```

Comment: As always...thank you @Dogbert. Can you also please whare with me what exactly `^port` means there?

Comment: It's the Pin Operator. See http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html#the-pin-operator. In short, that pattern will only match two element tuples where the first one equals the value of `port`.